# How do I get all the smart card readers on my system via WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, smartcard, pcsc

I want to get the DeviceID and Service of all PCSC smart card readers on my system using WMI. They're all connected via USB, so I query the WMI registry for all `Win32_PnPEntity`s. But I have no clue how to determine which devices are 'card readers'. Here's what I already have:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos =
new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\root\cimv2", @"Select * From Win32_PnPEntity");

ManagementObjectCollection mob = mos.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in mob)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: " + mo["DeviceID"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Service: " + mo["Service"].ToString());
}
```

I can't just filter on the device name, there's different brands/models of readers, and there's no common denominator. In the Device Manager they're all grouped under 'smart card readers', so there must be a(nother) way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the Device Class GUID on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):
**{50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5d-0000f805f530}**

> ```
> Smart Card Readers
> Class = SmartCardReader
> ClassGuid = {50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5d-0000f805f530}
> This class includes smart card readers.
> ```

So finally I came up with this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\root\cimv2",
@"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid = '{50DD5230-BA8A-11D1-BF5D-0000F805F530}'");
```

Which seems to give me what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any smart card readers here, so this is theoretical:

- What is the actual type (`__CLASS` property) of the returned instances. If a subtype, maybe looking for further instances of that type will help).
- What associations exist for the smart card devices:

  ```
  associators of {__RELPATH}
  ```

  where __RELPATH is the same named property from the `Win32_PnPEntity` instance. Also include associators of the associators.

  Note that most associated instances will represent things like the USB host/hub device, but others can be other aspects of the device (like a HDD will have both a `Win32_PhysicalDisk` instance in addition to a `Win32_PnPEntity`).

Also, to speed exploring the WMI types and objects I would suggest one of the console or GUI tools, this will be much easier than writing C# code. Eg. in PowerShell:

```
gwmi -query "select * from Win32_PnpEntity" | ft -autosize __RELPATH, DeviceID
```

easier to work with than the C# code (however it will need a very wide console window :-)).

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything relevant.