# Verify driver install through powershell

Tags: powershell, driver, wmi

I need to install a driver on a bunch of systems. (it should have come from MS but we are using kace for patching so i cant use wsus to push it out) So i found this oneliner RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 %path to inf%

Next is to put a check into it so it looks if the driver is installed first but I am having trouble finding the driver. I made an assumption that guidid or class from .inf will provide me with the info i need to check.

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=SmartCard
ClassGuid={990A2BD7-E738-46c7-B26F-1CF8FB9F1391}
Provider=%ProviderName%
CatalogFile=delta.cat
DriverVer=08/11/2015,8.4.9.0"

Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -Property * | where {$_.ClassGuid -like 
"990A2BD7-E738-46c7-B26F-1CF8FB9F1391"}
```

but I can not find the driver installed. I list all drivers and attempt to scroll through them to find this one and it's not there or it's called something else now.

eventual goal is something like this

```
if (!(Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, classguid | 
where {$_.classguid -like "*990A2BD7-E738-46c7-B26F-1CF8FB9F1391*"})) {echo 
do stuff} else { echo dont do stuff}
```

Any help in being able to identify if the driver is installed or not would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A little googling goes a long way as this has been asked a few times before. Here is a WMIC query against all the installed drivers on the system, then filters out everything except the smartcard class using the classGUID.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| where-object {$_.ClassGUID -eq "{50DD5230-BA8A-11D1-BF5D-0000F805F530}"} |Select *
```

Here is what got me to my answer if you need additional clarification.
[How do I get all the smart card readers on my system via WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812729/how-do-i-get-all-the-smart-card-readers-on-my-system-via-wmi)
https://superuser.com/questions/567927/get-driver-version-via-command-line-windows
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/

Comment: If you look at my question it is what i am doing already. If you read further I am saying I can not find the driver that has been loaded. Not "I am not able to search for the driver" but I do not know what criteria to search for because the info in INF does not provide the results expected.

Comment: Perhaps you should collect the data before the install, then collect it after the install, then Compare-Object the two lists. Regadless it sounds like this is a "How do I identify a driver" question. Not a powershell question since as you say you understand and have no problem with the powershell.

Comment: @user3225054 That command reveals the "DriverVersion" number which is, if its not the driver number you are expecting you should install the driver.