# How to identify USB Card Reader

Tags: windows, winapi, usb

I am trying to detect programmatically existence of USB Card Reader, which identifies itself as keyboard device. In Device Manager it looks like this:

[image: Device Manager]

The difference between real keyboard and card reader is only in device IDs. I have the following C# WMI code:

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * from Win32_Keyboard");
        ManagementObjectCollection keyboards = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject keyboard in keyboards)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (var property in keyboard.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value));
            }
        }
```

The output, like in Device Manager, differs only by device IDs:

```
Availability:
Caption: Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
ConfigManagerErrorCode: 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig: False
CreationClassName: Win32_Keyboard
Description: USB Input Device
DeviceID: USB\VID_04B3&PID_3025\5&DC4A972&0&3
ErrorCleared:
ErrorDescription:
InstallDate:
IsLocked:
LastErrorCode:
Layout: 00000409
Name: Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
NumberOfFunctionKeys: 12
Password:
PNPDeviceID: USB\VID_04B3&PID_3025\5&DC4A972&0&3
PowerManagementCapabilities:
PowerManagementSupported: False
Status: OK
StatusInfo:
SystemCreationClassName: Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName: ALEX19

Availability:
Caption: Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
ConfigManagerErrorCode: 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig: False
CreationClassName: Win32_Keyboard
Description: USB Input Device
DeviceID: USB\VID_0804&PID_0040\5&DC4A972&0&6
ErrorCleared:
ErrorDescription:
InstallDate:
IsLocked:
LastErrorCode:
Layout: 00000409
Name: Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
NumberOfFunctionKeys: 12
Password:
PNPDeviceID: USB\VID_0804&PID_0040\5&DC4A972&0&6
PowerManagementCapabilities:
PowerManagementSupported: False
Status: OK
StatusInfo:
SystemCreationClassName: Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName: ALEX19
```

However, Windows Settings shows this device as USB Card Reader:

[image: Settings]

How can I do the same, using .NET or native Windows API? OS is Windows 10 x64.

Note: this answer [How do I get all the smart card readers on my system via WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812729/how-do-i-get-all-the-smart-card-readers-on-my-system-via-wmi/10816542#10816542) suggests to use `SmartCardReader` class, but it doesn't work for me, card reader is not recognized.

Comment: in what is real question/problem/final target ? enumerate device interfaces for *SmartCardReaderGuid* ? enumerate readers/cards via *SCardxxx* api ? (when we connect via remote desktop readers from remote system can be virtually mapped), etc ?

Comment: for device be card reader it must register `SmartCardReaderGuid` interface and implement set of IOCTLs (`IOCTL_SMARTCARD_*`) but if device implement `SmartCardReaderGuid` - you view it under smart card readers node.. so i doubt that this device really card reader in strict windows sense.  real readers (and card) can be enumerated via `SCardListReaders` etc api. physical present devices -via `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` (different between this 2 ways can be in case terminal service session). so i and ask - what is your final target.

Comment: @RbMm: I also think that this device is not really card reader in strict windows sense. But Windows Settings shows it as "USB Card Reader". This means, there is some way to detect this.

Comment: i think this is device description only. look in device manager *details* tab and different property.. you can found device by many different way. this depend from what is really need at the end

Comment: Could you check [`SCardListReadersWithDeviceInstanceId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardlistreaderswithdeviceinstanceida) to see if it helps?

Comment: If you look closely at the screenshot provided, you'll see that Windows recognizes the USB card reader device as a *keyboard* (indicated by the keyboard icon). The accompanying text is probably pulled from some device description field, but used for display purposes only.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT: Thanks. `SCardListReaders` gives me 5 items, `SCardListReadersWithDeviceInstanceId` returns `SCARD_E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE` for each of them. This output doesn't contain the reader I am working with, and looks the same when it is connected or not.

Comment: @AlexF It works for me with USB smart card reader. Could you have a double check of the error `SCARD_E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE`? Because it is preferred to return from `SCardListReaders` instead of `SCardListReadersWithDeviceInstanceId`. `SCardListReadersWithDeviceInstanceId` gives me `SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_READER` when the reader name is not correct.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT: I checked, it behaves exactly as I described. It looks like my specific reader behaves like keyboard, and "USB Card Reader" is only name, as mentioned in previous posts. BTW, I have no idea what are 5 items returned by `SCardListReaders`, there is no additional readers on my computer, except one that behaves like keyboard. Thank you. It looks like there is no generic solution for this reader.